# How to hide tr of a table when one tr of checkbox is checked in jquery?

Tags: jquery

In a table i have tr's. In first tr i have checkbox.If that checkbox is unchecked , the other tr values must be hide.. If it is checked ,all other tr are shown.

I have shown it in fiddle,once check and say me solution please,

http://jsfiddle.net/Y39Bu/99/

### html

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="checker"></td>
</tr>
<div id='dependent-box'>
<tr>
  <td>Hii</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hii</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hii</td>
</tr>
```

### js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var checkbox = $('#checker'); 
    var dependent = $('#dependent-box');
    if (checkbox.attr('checked') !== undefined){
       dependent.show();
    } else {
        dependent.hide();
    }

    checkbox.change(function(e){
       dependent.toggle(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: You have invalid markup. div elements can not be siblings of table rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `tbody` instead of `div`.
**Note:** You can use many tbody in a table

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var checkbox = $('#checker'); 
        var dependent = $('#dependent-box');
        if (checkbox.attr('checked') !== undefined){
           dependent.show();
        } else {
            dependent.hide();
        }
        
        checkbox.change(function(e){
           dependent.toggle(); 
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="checker"></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id='dependent-box'>
    <tr>
      <td>Hii</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hii</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hii</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`div` cant be nested in `table`. Try like following.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var checkbox = $('#checker');
    var dependent = $('tr').not(':first');

    checkbox.change(function () {
        dependent.toggle(this.checked);
    }).change(); //auto execute after documet ready
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checker">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hii</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hii</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hii</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
 <table>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="checker"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="dependent-box">
  <td>Hii</td>
</tr>
<tr class="dependent-box">
  <td>Hii</td>
</tr>
<tr class="dependent-box">
  <td>Hii</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is javascript code

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    var checkbox = $('#checker'); 
    var dependent = $('.dependent-box');
    if (checkbox.attr('checked') !== undefined){
       dependent.show();
    } else {
        dependent.hide();
    }

    checkbox.change(function(e){
       dependent.toggle(); 
    });
});
```